# CSV database style changes in python like switching data into a file

Tags: python, csv

I'm having troubles coming up with a way to change data of a certain row in a csv file to the new value assigned through the script itself.

I hope you guys could help me with this problem.
Here is my code:

```
import csv

def Toevoeging_methode_plus(key_to_find, definition):
    if key_to_find in a:
        current = a[key_to_find]
        a[key_to_find] = int(current) + aantaltoevoeging


def Toevoeging_methode_minus(key_to_find, definition):
    if key_to_find in a:
        current = a[key_to_find]
        a[key_to_find] = int(current) - aantaltoevoeging
a = {}


with open("variabelen.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        a[row['Product']] = row['Aantal']
        print a

print("""
1. Toevoegen
2. Aftrek
3. Check
""")
askmenu = int(raw_input("Menu Nummer? "))
if askmenu is 1:
    toevoegproduct = raw_input("Productnummer > ")
    aantaltoevoeging = int(raw_input("Hoeveel > "))
    Toevoeging_methode_plus(toevoegproduct, aantaltoevoeging)
    print a

elif askmenu is 2:
    toevoegproduct = raw_input("Productnummer > ")
    aantaltoevoeging = int(raw_input("Hoeveel > "))
    Toevoeging_methode_minus(toevoegproduct, aantaltoevoeging)
    print a

elif askmenu is 3:
    checknummer = raw_input("Productnummer > ")
    if checknummer in a:
        print a[checknummer]

else:
    print "oops"
```

Comment: use the pandas library in python

Comment: can you post sample lines of your `variabelen .csv` ?

Comment: @HaifengZhang https://gyazo.com/29c8e2b4a039bb1b8789b59be1bc935e

Comment: @DannyBolland check my answer and make sure you read csv file other than excel file

Answer (score 0):

I made a csv file variabelen.csv from the link you provided(you need to convert to your Excel-File to csv file).

```
Product,Aantal
233,60
2234,1
```

I added comma delimiter in your `with open` block:

```
with open("variabelen.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        a[row['Product']] = row['Aantal']
        print a
```

Output:

```
{'233': '60'}
{'2234': '1', '233': '60'}

1. Toevoegen
2. Aftrek
3. Check

Menu Nummer? 1
Productnummer > 233
Hoeveel > 1
{'2234': '1', '233': 61}
```

Now the value of `233` is becoming 61 which is expected